# Dotspatial SpatialToolStrip buttons disabled

Tags: dotspatial

I have a stand alone map application that uses the DotSpatial.Controls.SpatialToolStrip control, when I added it to the form, only the 'Print' button is enabled, while all others are disabled. I went in to "Edit Item..." and set Enabled to True for all buttons, but when I run the application, all buttons are still disabled. How to turn them on?

Comment: Ok, I just followed the programmer guide to build a simple map viewer. This time, I removed the spatialtoolstrip control from designer, instead linking up the appManager, legend, and map controls, then recompile the project, this time, the toolbar showed up, but it is much different from the the SpatialToolStrip that is in the designer toolbox under DotSpatial tab. Also, I don't know how to add or remove buttons from the toolbar that was implicitly added to the form, how do one customize it? Why is the explicit SpatialToolStrip not working? is it by design?

Comment: I think I understand that the buttons on the tool strip are controlled by the presence of corresponding plugins in the project's 'Plugins' folder. Controlling the combination of buttons is hence done by adding or removing plugins

Comment: So, the question is: are we not supposed to use the DotSpatial.Controls.SpatialToolStrip control directly? I mean that are we not supposed to modified it in the form designer?